# Is there any way we can restore the "Additional CSS" after being erased?

Tags: css

My additional CSS got erased. how do I get that back?

Comment: Check with your hosting if you have backups

Comment: Has your theme name changed? Look in the wp_posts table in your database for post_type custom_css, or revision where the post_title is your old theme name.